# Sencha Touch 2 - what is init and initialize for?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

What does the init in the controller and initilize in the view do .??. I want a function that runs before a view loads . I am using a MVC .

Answer (score 10):

`init` is used in controllers to tell you when the after the controller is instantiated, but before the browser is ready. The `launch` method is called in your controller when the browser is ready (dom ready).

`init` is used in any components or subclasses of `Ext.Component` and is called when the class is instantiated. The configuration system for the class will have already been initialized by then.

Comment: @rdougan: Is it best practice to call parent `init` method in the sub-class, like using `this.callParent(arguments)` ?

Comment: @SayemAhmed yes, although `init` is an empty function in `Ext.app.Controller` and `Ext.app.Application`.